# Store bought frozen coconut milk

Tags: refrigerator, frozen, coconut, coconut-milk

For how long can you keep **store bought** packaged frozen coconut milk in the refrigerator after it's been thawed?

Comment: I've never seen frozen coconut milk available for sale at my local stores -- is there a brand name on it that we might be able to do some digging into?  (or is it just generic packaging, like the grocery store did it themselves?)

Answer (score 2):

you can keep the coconut milk for 3 more days and that's the maximum after this time you find that it begins to coagulate and that smells fowl. i bought coconut milk for a prawn recipe for valentines day http://www.mariellasmenu.com.ng/2016/02/tiger-prawns-in-coconut-milk-valentines.html and i had some left over, , even though it was in the freezer, it had gone bad

Comment: While I believe that coconut milk could go bad in a few days, it's pretty unlikely that it went bad in the freezer - it was probably the time it spent outside the freezer beforehand, or the time after thawing.

Comment: Yes i agree with you, it was the time it spent outside the freezer. once this happens there is no redemption even if you put it back. you have to toss it